# Convert csv timestamp from UTC to Hawaiian timezone

Tags: python, csv, datetime, python-dateutil

I have a csv of data which is time-stamped to UTC, but needs to have the local time from Hawaii (UTC-10). Ideally I'd add a new column to the csv with the Hawaiian time alongside the UTC time, followed by the data.

[Here is the csv file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3QYp.jpg), with the date-time on the first column. The format is a little odd as it has "year-month-date hour/minute/second" as normal but is then followed by "UTC" which I think might be causing me a problem.

I've got some simple code to extract the time column, assign it to UTC time (as timestamps are of unknown timezone) and then convert it to UTC-10.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

# read the file in csv 
K = pd.read_csv("kona_python.csv")

# time series data selection
UTCtime = K.iloc[:,0] 

# access timezones:
utc_timezome = tz.gettz('UTC')
hawaii_timezone = tz.gettz('US/Hawaii')

# feeding in the csv column data
utc = UTCtime

# set the datetime object to the UTC timezone
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo = utc_timezome)

# convert time zone to Hawaii
hawaii = utc.astimezone(hawaii_timezone)
```

However it runs with [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiNgt.jpg), where tzinfo is not expected. Am I using dateutil correctly? Or is there a simpler way to do this? Any help much appreciated!

**Update** - csv sample:

```
UTC timestamp   A   B   C   D   E   F
2018-07-20 22:22:06 UTC 1.27    21.64   1.11    0.37    22.31   0.33
2018-07-20 22:23:25 UTC 1.4 21.82   0.33    0.75    22.59   0.33
2018-07-20 22:24:45 UTC 2.09    20.31   0.93    1.55    21.05   0.4
2018-07-20 22:26:05 UTC 0.8 21.34   0.93    1.36    20.89   0.4
2018-07-20 22:27:24 UTC 0.4 19.93   0.93    1.37    22.58   0.24
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the code above (for example utc is a Series of strings, not of time stamps, then the replace function can not be applied on a series as if it is a timezone), see below for a working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

# read the file in csv 
K = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

# time series data selection
UTCtime = K.iloc[:,0] 

# access timezones:
hawaii_timezone = tz.gettz('US/Hawaii')

# convert the string to datime
utc = UTCtime.apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC"))

# convert time zone to Hawaii (first localize to utc)
hawaii = utc.apply(lambda x : x.tz_localize('utc').astimezone(hawaii_timezone))

print (hawaii)
```

Code was tested with this csv:

```
col,col,col
2018-07-20 22:22:06 UTC,a,b
```

Comment: Thanks vladmihaisima! Unfortunately I'm still getting an error message: 

ValueError: time data 'UTC timestamp' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC'

Any ideas why this would be? As far as I can see the excel timestamp '2018-07-20 22:26:05 UTC' does match that format...?

Comment: Nothing obvious comes to mind. To progress would suggest to put in the question the first 2-3 lines of your csv as it is on disk, so that I can try to reproduce your problem. You can also try with the example I put in the answer to check...

Comment: Hi vladmihaisima, how would I put the csv into the question? I can't find a way to give you the actual file...

Comment: If it is a comma separated file (probably) you can open it with a text editor and paste the first 4-5 lines (don't need all) in the original question (as a new code).

Comment: By the looks of your file it is not comma separated, but tab separated. I would suggest trying with K = pd.read_csv("kona_python.csv", sep="\t")